# Choose what rigid-body is affected by a force field in Blender 2.9

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision, collections, force-fields

I have a conundrum,

I have a bunch of rigid-bodies that I would like to travel to different locations.
On their voyage to their location I’d like them to be able to interact and collide with any other rigid-body it meets along the way. (This could be hundreds of rigid-bodies)

One way I thought of setting the target destination would be to use a force field. However, is there a way to make it so the force-field will only affect one rigid body of my choosing? At the moment when I try it, it affects all of the rigid bodies.

Something like this would be great…[image]

If not, is there any other method for getting a rigid body to travel to a specific target location but be able to collided with other rigid-bodies along the way?

Any ideas welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hello, it doesn't seem to exist, it would make sense to create layers for force fields as well, probably a good request for Right-Click Select: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/

Comment: See if this answer works - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35683/force-fields-affecting-selected-rigid-body-objects . It uses soft bodies instead of rigid bodies but should yield the desired result.